# Firefox addons break when restoring a tab

Tags: firefox

Firefox is a memory and CPU hog. It would be great if you could tell Firefox only to give CPU to the active tab. But that does not seem possible.

So I often run this to kill all running tabs (without closing them):

```
ps aux |G firefox contentproc childID -v grep |field 2 | xargs -r kill
```

This works great: When you go to a tab you can restore the tab again.

But there is one big drawback: Some add-ons (e.g. BitWarden, PureVPN, KillSticky, Privacy Badger and probably others) stop working.

How can I get those back working without restarting Firefox completely?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Add-on manager (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>). Disable the add-on with the slider. Re-enable the add-on with the slider.

Now the add-on works again.